# Obtain several id if vote > 1

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite query like this:

```
SELECT videos_actors.id_actor FROM videos_actors
INNER JOIN videos ON videos.id = videos_actors.id_video
WHERE videos.vote IS NOT NULL
```

So I have basically one table "`videos`" like this:

```
id | vote
```

and one table "`videos_actors`" like this:

```
id_video | id_actor
```

And I want to get a list of `id_actor`, with vote * id_actor. Basically, if a video is voted 3 times, I want 3 times in the list the id of the actor in this video.

For instance, let's take a table "videos" like this:

```
1 | 3 votes
```

videos_actors:

```
1 | 45
```

Video number 1 is voted 3 times, so I want my query to return:

```
[ 45, 45, 45 ]
```

Do you have an idea about how to do that ?

Comment: Is there only one actor per video?

Comment: Nope, in the table videos_actors you can have:

1 | 45, 
1 | 46

Comment: So what would you want to return in that case?

Comment: [ 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46 ]. But Dolph suggested an answer which allows me to obtain such a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just include `videos.vote` in your results, then you get the exact data you're looking for without returning as much data from the SQL server:

```
SELECT videos_actors.id_actor, videos.vote
FROM videos_actors
INNER JOIN videos ON videos.id = videos_actors.id_video
WHERE videos.vote IS NOT NULL
```

Then manipulate the data in the application rather than unnecessarily bulking up the result set.

Comment: You are right. Is it better to do the treatments in the application than in the query ? The app is local, written in python with sqlite.